# How to find out which child component caused the parent?

Tags: vuejs2

There are several components, at first there is one big one that creates other components.

http://joxi.ru/DmBl36VFJwq4NA

They in turn contain other components.

http://joxi.ru/82QZGyRfwj89wA

On the page there are various clickable elements that open a popup with a select. Popup is another vue component. Popup accepts data and displays it in a select. Next, the user selects something in this select and presses the confirmation button.

I need to associate the result of the popup with a specific element in the component. The problem is that the user can open a pop-up of all three components. Clicks on all these items open pop-up

http://joxi.ru/52a53oGUE4lke2

but all these elements are in different components

There is code of main component which is contains pop-up component

```
    <template>
        <!--some html-->
            <select-modal @close-modal="hideSelectModal" v-if="selectModal" :data="selectModalData"></select-modal>
        <!--some html-->
    </template>

<script>
        data: () => ({
            selectModal: false,
            selectModalData: {},
        }),

        methods: {
            showSelectModal(data, event){

                if(this.selectModal === true){
                    this.hideSelectModal();
                }else{
                    this.selectModalData = data;
                    this.selectModal = true;
                }
            },

            hideSelectModal(){
                this.selectModalData = [];
                this.selectModal = false;
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

There is code of how i pass data from child compoentns to parent

```
methods: {
    showModal(dataArr, selectedItem, action, event){

        let selectObject = {items: [], selected: selectedItem, action: action};
        for(let i = 0; i < dataArr.length; i++){
            selectObject.items.push({value: dataArr[i].id, text: dataArr[i].name})
        }

        this.$emit('open-modal', selectObject, event);
    }
},
```

there is update method inside pop-up component

```
  update(){

      if(this.value === null){
          return false;
      }

      switch(this.data.action){
          case 'serie':
              this.updateGameSerie();
              break;
          case 'game':
              this.updateGame();
              break;
          case 'set':
              this.updateSet();
              break;
      }
  },
```

But I think that pass action as a string not a good idea. Mb there is some stack trace?

There are two troubles.

1 - how the popup can find out from which component the data was transferred to it?

2 - How to associate the pop-up selection result with the data of the child components in order to redefine them?

Comment: Can you first use a backdrop/overlay as a container for the modals, to prevent multiple popups from being triggered at the same time?

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean, because i am beginner in vue

Comment: For example, check out this [nice component](https://sweet-modal-vue.adepto.as/) and try out the one called "Dark with Blocking Error". If you could implement something like that in your modal, you might not have to worry about data being associated with the wrong elements any more.

Comment: My problem is that I generally can not associate a specific component with a popup

Comment: You seem to be doing it right already. You have a method called `showModal`, I thought you're already attaching this to each of the buttons, passing the specific parameters. Like `@click="showModal(data, ...)"`. BTW, I am also new in VueJS, and you're actually building a nice app there! ;)